# TeamCity error when inputting BitBucket repository

Tags: bitbucket, teamcity

I am trying to create a new project in *TeamCity*, but when I input my *BitBucket* repository link it gives me this error:

> "List remote refs failed: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException
>   https://bitbucket.org/XXXX/XXXX.git: not authorized"

I use my repo link: "https://XXXX@bitbucket.org/XXXX/XXXX.git"

Comment: I never used TeamCity but I can imagine that this is a credentials/authorization issue. Is this a public or a private repository? If it's private, make sure that you properly setup the credentials so that your build server (TeamCity) has read access to the repository.
I'd expect the TeamCity documentation to contain detailed examples for this.

Comment: @JoelBodenmann I have setup OAuth correctly in BitBucket and connected it to my TeamCity server. It sees the repository, but still the same error. Seems pointless for the OAuth then? Maybe I can try SSH key.